# Version 4.1.9 throws an error: "name": "ApplicationError", "message": "Email already taken" via Postman

Tags: strapi

#### My System information

- Node.js version: v16.13.0
- NPM version: 8.1.0
- Strapi version: 4.1.9
- Database: Postgres
- Operating system: MacOS

#### The Issue

I recently setup an instance of Strapi  and Postgres via railway (https://railway.app), and tried making a few request to test the api. Upon making POST request to fetch/ update a user that was originally setup through Strapi admin, I am getting an `Email already taken` 404 error message.

#### Screenshots

https://freeimage.host/i/HCvcw0P

#### Steps to reproduce the behavior

1. Configured user `Content-Type` by adding a `user_role` field via Strapi admin (Note that this is not meant to replace the default Strapi  user role).
2. Saved the file, and the entry was successfully saved in the database.
3. Made a `GET Request` to `https://my-railway-url/api/users`   to retrieve `ALL USERS` successfully.
4. I made a Post request to `https://my-railway-url/api/auth/local` to get user info along with the `JWT token`
5. Received a `JWT token` along with user information.
6. Copied the `JWT Token` and made another POST request - with `body set to JSON`, entered info to update the existing user
7. Got an error `Email already taken`

#### Expected behavior

User information updated with the new entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `strapi` `user-permissions` plugin, has it's own logic of controllers, with would not be the same as standard content-type api's

to use it you have following routes:

```js
// LOGIN
url: `api/auth/local`
method: POST
body: {
  identifier: string
  password: string
}
```

```js
// ME get current authenticated user
url: `api/users/me`   // you can add '?populate=*' here
method: GET
```

```js
// UPDATE USER
url: `api/users/:id`  // you can add '?populate=*' here
method: POST
body: {
  ...data // < user data
}
```

seems `?id=3` is invalid in your query, should be `/api/users/3`